# Merge XML files while ignoring duplicate elements

Tags: xml, linux, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have 2 XML files that I want to merge, but I do not want to change any of the existing elements from the original file. What is the best way to do this on a linux system?

Note: there are posts about using XSLT that seem to be close to what I need, but I do not have an XSLT processor installed (nor do I have rights to install it). That said, I do have `xsltproc` installed, but I'm not sure that this will help. If `xsltproc` would help, please provide a suitable command line example.

Here is snippet of the original file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance">
   <Comment>This file was automatically generated.</Comment>
   <FieldAttrs>
      <Name>FieldAttrsAll</Name>
      <Field>
         <Name>wLegExchInstIds</Name>
         <Fid>6203</Fid>
         <Type>StringVector</Type>
         <CheckModified>true</CheckModified>
         <PublishField>true</PublishField>
         <ClearDaily>false</ClearDaily>
      </Field>

      <Field>
         <Name>wPartitionId</Name>
         <Fid>5886</Fid>
         <Type>Integer</Type>
         <CheckModified>true</CheckModified>
         <PublishField>true</PublishField>
         <ClearDaily>false</ClearDaily>
      </Field>
   </FieldAttrs>
</config>
```

And here is the new file I need to merge:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance">
   <Comment>This file was automatically generated.</Comment>
   <FieldAttrs>
      <Name>FieldAttrsAll</Name>
      <Field>
         <Name>wLegExchInstIds</Name>
         <Fid>6203</Fid>
         <Type>StringVector</Type>
         <CheckModified>false</CheckModified>
         <PublishField>false</PublishField>
         <ClearDaily>false</ClearDaily>
      </Field>    
      <Field>
         <Name>wPartitionId</Name>
         <Fid>5886</Fid>
         <Type>Integer</Type>
         <CheckModified>false</CheckModified>
         <PublishField>false</PublishField>
         <ClearDaily>false</ClearDaily>
      </Field>    
      <Field>
         <Name>wUnverifiedPriceIndicator</Name>
         <Fid>5885</Fid>
         <Type>Bool</Type>
         <CheckModified>true</CheckModified>
         <PublishField>true</PublishField>
         <ClearDaily>true</ClearDaily>
      </Field>
      <Field>
         <Name>wCorrIsIrregular</Name>
         <Fid>5884</Fid>
         <Type>Bool</Type>
         <CheckModified>false</CheckModified>
         <PublishField>true</PublishField>
         <ClearDaily>true</ClearDaily>
      </Field>

   </FieldAttrs>
</config>
```

In particular note 2 things:

1. the existing values of some of the elements changed in the new file, and
2. there are new elements added in the new file.

Given the above files, I want the output to look as follows:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Comment>This file was automatically generated.</Comment>
   <FieldAttrs>
      <Name>FieldAttrsAll</Name>
      <Field>
         <Name>wLegExchInstIds</Name>
         <Fid>6203</Fid>
         <Type>StringVector</Type>
         <CheckModified>true</CheckModified>
         <PublishField>true</PublishField>
         <ClearDaily>false</ClearDaily>
      </Field>

      <Field>
         <Name>wPartitionId</Name>
         <Fid>5886</Fid>
         <Type>Integer</Type>
         <CheckModified>true</CheckModified>
         <PublishField>true</PublishField>
         <ClearDaily>false</ClearDaily>
      </Field>

      <Field>
         <Name>wUnverifiedPriceIndicator</Name>
         <Fid>5885</Fid>
         <Type>Bool</Type>
         <CheckModified>true</CheckModified>
         <PublishField>true</PublishField>
         <ClearDaily>true</ClearDaily>
      </Field>
      <Field>
         <Name>wCorrIsIrregular</Name>
         <Fid>5884</Fid>
         <Type>Bool</Type>
         <CheckModified>false</CheckModified>
         <PublishField>true</PublishField>
         <ClearDaily>true</ClearDaily>
      </Field>    
   </FieldAttrs>
</config>
```

Comment: I changed a typo in your third XML snippet: "<cnfig..." to "<config...".

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following XSLT that uses the `document()` function to parse from external XML. This approach actually begins with the larger XML file parsing values from the shorter XML to remove duplicates as opposed to add distinct nodes:

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file, references second XML file to be saved in same directory as first one)*

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <!-- Identity Transform -->
 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>      
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>  

 <xsl:template match="FieldAttrs">
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:copy-of select="Name"/>
     <xsl:copy-of select="document('ShorterXML.xml')/config/FieldAttrs/Field"/>
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Field[Name=document('ShorterXML.xml')/config/FieldAttrs/Field/Name]"/>

</xsl:transform>
```

**Linux** command line *(references only one of the XML files as input all in same directory)*

```
xsltproc transform.xsl LongerXML.xml -o output.xml
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Comment>This file was automatically generated.</Comment>
  <FieldAttrs>
    <Name>FieldAttrsAll</Name>
    <Field>
      <Name>wLegExchInstIds</Name>
      <Fid>6203</Fid>
      <Type>StringVector</Type>
      <CheckModified>true</CheckModified>
      <PublishField>true</PublishField>
      <ClearDaily>false</ClearDaily>
    </Field>
    <Field>
      <Name>wPartitionId</Name>
      <Fid>5886</Fid>
      <Type>Integer</Type>
      <CheckModified>true</CheckModified>
      <PublishField>true</PublishField>
      <ClearDaily>false</ClearDaily>
    </Field>
    <Name>FieldAttrsAll</Name>
    <Field>
      <Name>wUnverifiedPriceIndicator</Name>
      <Fid>5885</Fid>
      <Type>Bool</Type>
      <CheckModified>true</CheckModified>
      <PublishField>true</PublishField>
      <ClearDaily>true</ClearDaily>
    </Field>
    <Field>
      <Name>wCorrIsIrregular</Name>
      <Fid>5884</Fid>
      <Type>Bool</Type>
      <CheckModified>false</CheckModified>
      <PublishField>true</PublishField>
      <ClearDaily>true</ClearDaily>
    </Field>
  </FieldAttrs>
</config>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful.  I will have to read up on the syntax of using xslt

Comment: Curious, did you run it? How did it go?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to merge the two files in the given way using [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh), a wrapper around [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML) that uses `libxml2` under the hood:

```
my $old := open old.xml ;
$field := hash Name //Field ;

open new.xml ;
for //Field {
    $exists = xsh:lookup('field', Name) ;
    if not($exists)
        copy . into $old/config/FieldAttrs ;
}

save :f merged.xml $old ;
```

Comment: unfortunately I don't have xsh on the system (and again I do not have root access to install - I tried installing into my home dir but it failed on some dependencies)